# Reversing a Stack with the help of another empty stack in C++ using recursion?

Tags: c++, c++11

My approach to this question is that as recursion works using stack ,So if my input is some n numbers,recursion will provide me reverse of the stack from  1 to n and for adding 0th element ,I'll first copy the stack(Say S1) into an empty stack(Say S2) and push 0th element into S1 and then copy back the element from Stack S2 to S1. This is my code and I'm not able to figure out the problem to implement my approach.

```
void reverseStack(stack<int> &input, stack<int> &extra) {
    if(input.size()==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int x=input.top();
    input.pop();
    reverseStack(input,extra);
    for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
    {
        extra.push(input.top());
        input.pop();
    }
    input.push(x);
    for(int i=0;i<extra.size();i++)
    {
        input.push(extra.top());
        extra.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: @UKMonkey That cannot be used (easily), as `std::stack` provides no iterator interface and the underlying container is `protected` (which opens the door to some trickery to use `std::reverse()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a stack is a first-in-last-out (FILO) data structure, reversing a stack can be achieved by repeatedly removing the top element and pushing it into another stack. At the end, simply replace the original stack with the reversed one. Usage of `move` semantics avoids any deep copies.

```
template<typename T>
void reverse(std::stack<T> &the_stack)
{
    std::stack<T> reverse_stack;
    while(!the_stack.empty()) {
        reverse_stack.push(std::move(the_stack.top()));
        the_stack.pop();
    }
    the_stack = std::move(reverse_stack);
}
```

This does not use recursion, but any iterative program can be re-formulated as a recursive program, for example

```
template<typename T>
void reverse_recursive(std::stack<T> &the_stack,
                       std::stack<T> &reverse_stack)
{
    if(!the_stack.empty()) {
        reverse_stack.push(std::move(the_stack.top()));
        the_stack.pop();
        reverse_recursive(the_stack,reverse_stack);
    } else 
        the_stack = std::move(reverse_stack);
}

template<typename T>
void reverse(std::stack<T> &the_stack)
{
    std::stack<T> auxiliary_stack;
    reverse_recursive(the_stack,auxiliary_stack);
}
```

which is more involved than the simple iterative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare size variables for input and extra stack.

```
void reverseStack(stack<int> &input, stack<int> &extra) {
// Write your code here
  if(input.size()==0)
{
    return;
}
int x=input.top();
input.pop();
reverseStack(input,extra);
int size1 = input.size();
for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
{
    extra.push(input.top());
    input.pop();
}
input.push(x);
int size2 = extra.size();
for(int i=0;i<size2;i++)
{
    input.push(extra.top());
    extra.pop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverseStack(stack<int> &input, stack<int> &extra) {
    if(input.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    int x = input.top();
    input.pop();
    reverseStack(input,extra);
    while(!input.empty())
    {
        extra.push(input.top());
        input.pop();
    }
    input.push(x);
    while(!extra.empty())
    {
        input.push(extra.top());
        extra.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverseStack(stack<int> &input, stack<int> &extra) {
if(input.empty())
{
    return;
}
int x = input.peek();
input.pop();
reverseStack(input,extra);
while(!input.empty())
{
    extra.push(input.peek());
    input.pop();
}
input.push(x);
while(!extra.empty())
{
    input.push(extra.peek());
    extra.pop();
}
```

}